# Weird use of void

Tags: c, void

I've been going through some C source code and I noticed the following:

```
void some_func (char *foo, struct bar *baz)
{
    (void)foo;
    (void)baz;
}
```

Why is `void` used here? I know `(void)` before an expression explicitly indicates that the value is *thrown away*; but can someone please explain me the rationale for such an use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This code ensures that you won't get a compiler warning about foo and baz being unused.

Comment: It may not be a case of something left TODO: this could be the final state of the code.  For example, this function could be a callback, and those parameters really aren't used.

Comment: "Ensure" is a bit too strong.  It'll work for some compilers, but apparently it's not universal: http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/

Comment: It seems like it might be a better idea to use compiler directives to throw out those specific warnings.  It sounds like neither solution is portable, so you might as well do the one that better documents your intent.

Comment: +1 for callback. That's precisely when you don't get to choose your arguments.

Comment: If the intention was to avoid a compiler warning on unused arguments, would it not be a clearer statement of intent to leave the names out of the parameter list altogether? i.e. 'void some_func(char*, struct bar*)'

Comment: @Will ANSI/ISO C will not allow you to have unnamed parameters in functions.

Comment: Just wanted to say jamesdlin's link is a beautiful and portable alternative to this!

Answer (score 8):

Most likely, someone was building this code with a compiler that emits warnings for unused arguments, and wanted to suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 6):

The most likely reason for those variables to appear at all in the function is to remove any warnings about unused arguments.

However, since this is likely to introduce yet *another* warning (since you're probably using a higher-than-normal warning level), the author goes an extra step to remove those as well.

In C, the statement

```
42;
```

is actually valid, though not very useful. If you compile:

```
int main (void) {
    42;
    return 0;
}
```

it will not complain (normally). However, if you compile that with `gcc -Wall -pedantic` (for example), you'll get something like:

```
prog.c: In function `main':
prog.c:2: warning: statement with no effect
```

because the compiler, rightly so, thinks you've gone crazy.

Putting a `(void)` cast before something that generates a value, like the `42;` will explicitly state that you don't care about the value.

I've seen this used on some anal-retentive compilers which insist that, because a function like `printf` actually returns a value, you must be mad for ignoring it, leading to such atrocities as:

```
(void)printf ("Hello, world.\n");
(void)strcpy (dest, src);
```

:-)

---

By way of example, if you compile:

```
void some_func (char *foo) {}
int main (void) { some_func (0); return 0; }
```

with `gcc -Wall -W -pedantic`, you'll get:

```
warning: unused parameter `foo'
```

If you "use" the parameter:

```
void some_func (char *foo) { foo; }
```

you'll get

```
warning: statement with no effect
```

However, if you use the parameter and explicitly ignore the result:

```
void some_func (char *foo) { (void)foo; }
```

you'll get no warnings at all.

Comment: I am aware of this use (calling a function which returns something and sticking a `(void)` in front of it to ignore the value returned); I was merely curious about why one would do this to an argument.

Comment: @theDigtialEngel, see the update. Simply mentioning the parameter in the function replaces one warning with another. You have to void-cast it to get rid of that second warning.

Comment: In fact you can go even further and just drop the parameter name: `void some_func(char *) {}`  Got this from http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/, which was posted in a comment by jamesdlin.  Turn that into `template<typename T> void ignore(T const&) {}` and you have a nice general-purpose ignorifier! :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I don't think you can drop parameter names in standard C (as opposed to C++).

Comment: @theDigtialEngel: Interesting.  And since it's C not C++, my template idea is out the window :)  In that case I propose `void ignore(...) {}`.