# Please Explain The Meaning of Following Cast

Tags: c, casting, void

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird use of void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083851/weird-use-of-void)

I was reading C code and came across the following. Can somebody please explain what this does?

```
static int do_spawn(const char *filename)
{
  (void)filename;
  // todo: fill this in
  return -1;
}
```

Specifically, what is the (void) filename doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compilers sometimes complain about unused parameters; the `(void)` "cast" is simply a way to use the variable in a void, non-side-effect context so that the compiler won't complain about it being "unused".

**EDIT**: As rodrigo points out below, the compiler warning can be suppressed without the `(void)` prefix, but then another warning (about the expression having no effect) may appear instead. So `(void)filename` is how you might prevent both warnings.

Comment: Actually, the cast to `void` wasn't necessary to remove the warning. But without it, sometimes another warning about "expression has no effect" would appear. The `(void)` avoided that.

Comment: @James: I've never seen it in any compiler I've ever used, but I'm also pretty young. :-)

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra` warns `unused parameter ‘filename’`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Okay, I've switched to present tense. We cool now? :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's preventing a warning about an unused parameter, nothing more.